# How to use the translator package with beamer?

Tags: beamer, languages

I'd like to have my headers like Theorem, Definition etc. in a `beamer` presentation translated to Polish.  After skimming through the last pages of `beamer` user guide, I tried `\usepackage[polish]{translator}`, but it resulted in "Option clash for package translator".  Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put your language option amongst the class options where both `babel` and the `translator` package (implicitly loaded by `beamer`) can see it:

```
\documentclass[polish]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}[Theorem]

  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

An alternative for your implicit question "How do I pass options to a package that I don't load myself" is to use `\PassOptionsToPackage`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{polish}{translator}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
```

Comment: Thanks!  And what if I don't want to use `babel`?

Comment: OK, the `\PassOptionsToPackage` worked without `babel`.  Incidentally, there was another error: there's a bug in the Polish dictionary for translator; I'll email the maintainer.

Comment: And just `[polish]{beamer}` works even better.  Thanks again!