# Color names in the current language in LaTeX

Tags: color, babel, languages, german

Let's say we wish to verbalize the colors used in a document in the current language:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,ngerman]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\actionColor}{blue}
\newcommand{\actionColorGerman}{blau}
\begin{document}
Die Aktionen werden \ifdefempty{\actionColorGerman}{in Textfarbe}{\actionColorGerman} gesetzt.
\end{document}
```

yields

> Die Aktionen werden blau gesetzt.

(Which means that the actions (whatever an action might mean in my text) are typeset blue.)

The current code is bad because `\actionColor` and `\actionColorGerman` are not tied together by a command.  For example, if you change/remove one (say, `blue`), you may forget to change/remove the other (here, `blau`). Moreover, if you have a dozen of different semantic color macros `\doodahXYZColor` evaluating to `blue` and another dozen `\gimmickXYZColor` evaluating to `red`, you'd have to add a dozen of translations `\doodahXYZColorGerman` evaluating to `blau` and another dozen of translations `\gimmickXYZColorGerman` evaluating to `rot`.  This is useless duplication.

Has some package already done the exercise of automatically translating the color names?  I don't wish to reinvent the bicycle. Ideally, I'd like to have a macro

```
\colorInCurrentLanguage{…}
```

that takes an argument (in our MWE, `\actionColor`) and returns its translation in the current document language (in our MWE, `blau`).

For my current purposes, translations into German would do.

Comment: I guess taking a list of color names and copy pasting it into Google translate would be an option? This seems oddly specific.

Comment: [q176058](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176058) seems like one way to solve this.

Comment: @user202729 No, as some kind of switch statement taking an English color and returning a foreign-language color (and a default string if no translation has been found) would still be needed. Also, translations may vary. And, most important, I don't wish to bloat up the code with strings potentially already stored somewhere deep in babel, xcolor, or related packages.

Comment: Grepping for `blau` in my TeXlive directory the only relevant I can find is https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrXlS.png . So I'd say not particularly usable here.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but I wonder why? color is conceptually like a command name we happened to choose `\color{blue}` rather than `\blue` but that was an arbitrary choice. You could translate all command names such as `\begin` (context had that posibility) but why just colors?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I my text I wish to explain which parts are typeset in which colors (call it a legend). So, the blue color in LaTeX sources gets shown in the output also as the German text *blau*; this is what I wish to show to the reader. As the sources don't have verbatim `blue` each time I use this color but rather a semantic macro for it (e.g., `\actionColor`), I don't wish to write *blau* each time either. Rather, `\actionColor` should be automatically displayed in German on need (say, via `\GetTranslation{\actionColor}`).

Comment: @user202729  i.stack.imgur.com/mrXlS.png is found in mkii an mkiv dirs on my machine. Usable, probably, for outdated ConTeXt versions only.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The package `translations` doesn't like macros as arguments. Running `pdflatex` on https://pastebin.com/raw/AdqmEaPp produces `Die Aktionen werden “actionColor gesetzt.` in the output PDF file. That's NOT what we want :-(.

Comment: @AlbertNash You're going to need `\expandafter` it seems: `Die Aktionen werden \ifdefempty{\actionColor}{in Textfarbe}{\expandafter\GetTranslation\expandafter{\actionColor}} gesetzt.`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This is quite a kludge but, hey, it works! Thanks!  It seems that using the `translator` package would allow for writing `\newtranslation[to=German]{blue}{blau}` in the preamble and simply `\translate{\actionColor}` in the document text, without any `\expandafter`.  So why have you suggested `translations` and not `translator`?

Comment: @AlbertNash Both packages are mentioned in the linked question. I don't have any experience with any of them. I certainly don't know the advantages or drawbacks of either package. Having to use `\expandafter` isn't the worst thing (since you can always let a macro do this).maybe the `translation` package provides more tools and macros to solve this. (Though, I'm surprised it breaks. I've expected it to expand its argument in the first place.)