# translator vs. translations

Tags: translate, translations, translator, expandafter

What's the point of having two packages *translations* and *translator* with roughly the same main functionality?

Let's consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,french,ngerman]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translations}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\actionColor}{blue}
\DeclareTranslation{ngerman}{blue}{blau}
\DeclareTranslation{french}{blue}{bleu}
\newtranslation[to=German]{blue}{blau}
\newtranslation[to=French]{blue}{bleu}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\GetTranslation\expandafter{\actionColor}
\translate{\actionColor}
\selectlanguage{french}
\expandafter\GetTranslation\expandafter{\actionColor}
\translate{\actionColor}%
\end{document}
```

As expected, the output is

> blau blau bleu bleu

Am I missing anything? Alright, the author of *translations* said he wanted an expandable version of *translator*'s `\translate` command, but in which context would this be an advantage? In my context, having to think of two additional `\expandafter`s per call seems more a disadvantage to me.

Comment: You just asked [a question earlier today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665781/color-names-in-the-current-language-in-latex) whose answer required an expandable argument. I’m not sure what other kind of example you are looking for.

Comment: Expandable can be useful if the translation should also work in the bookmarks or when writing to a file. Apart from this: if someone wants to write another package who should  forbid it?

Comment: @Ulrike IIRC bookmarks were the original reason for needing and wanting an alternative to translator

Comment: apart from any specifics about that package your question is asking why, in the 40 year history of latex, two people would write packages with similar functionality. Surely that is simply expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expandable commands work also in bookmarks. And to avoid the \expandafter you can simply define your own wrapper command (I use `\ExpandArgs` which is new in LaTeX, but `\expandafter` would work too).

```
\documentclass[USenglish,french,ngerman]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translations}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\actionColor}{blue}
\DeclareTranslation{ngerman}{blue}{blau}
\DeclareTranslation{french}{blue}{bleu}
\newtranslation[to=German]{blue}{blau}
\newtranslation[to=French]{blue}{bleu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\GetCmdTranslation[1]{\ExpandArgs{o}\GetTranslation{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{\GetCmdTranslation{\actionColor}--\translate{\actionColor}}
\end{document}
```

As you can see only one of the translations finds it way into the bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: Thx. The log says that `\translate ` is simply removed from the `\section{…}` line.